# Why do I get the 'Cannot GET /page ' error on my node.js application when it Reloads/Refresh?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a **Nodejs** application hosted in a shared hosting service. The **application** is serving an Angular app in the **public_html** folder. My app runs correctly but when sub-routes reload i get the error below.

Cannot GET /sub-route

but this only happens to **sub-routes**.

I have my node server app set as such:

```
//import modules
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    cors = require('cors');
    path = require('path');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//import database connection from dbconnect.js file
var mysql = require('./dbconnect/dbconnect');

//Parse as urlencoded and json.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//adding middleware - cors
app.use(cors());

//Http logger
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Uncomment for production
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public')));

app.use(function (req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});    

//import routes
var user = require('./routes/Users');  
    route = require('./routes/route');
    router = require('./router/router');
//adding routes
app.use('/api', user, route, router);

app.listen(port, function() {console.log('Server started at http://localhost:'+port+'/');});
```

My .htaccess file   is  configured as

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

I tried changing this line

```
app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public')));
```

to

```
app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html')));
```

It eliminates the error, but then my api routes do not work when i do this.

Comment: is it an angular application ?

Comment: If the frontend is in angular you need to serve dist folder to `app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html')));` instead of sending index.html . If you are using node as just an API then you need to use `HashLocationStrategy` in your angular app

Comment: @joel-joseph yes it is an angular application

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Comment: I back @SathwikGangisetty, activate the hash location strategy, and you're good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys this worked out for me. By moving the API routes above the catch all other routes and returning index which was missing   on my code.

Based on https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli,  i changed my code from:

```
// Point static path to public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public')));       

//import routes
var user = require('./routes/Users');  
    route = require('./routes/route');
    router = require('./router/router');
//adding routes
app.use('/api', user, route, router);
```

**to**

```
// Point static path to public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//import routes from /routes/routes.js
  var user = require('./routes/Users');  
      route = require('./routes/route');
      router = require('./router/router');
 //adding routes
   app.use('/api', user, route, router);

 // Catch all other routes and return the index file
   app.get('/*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 
    '/public/index.html'));
   });
```